# DNS Redirecting into Another website

Tags: redirect, dns, web-hosting

I own a website(A) and used blogger platform in web domain.Last month blog get deleted and i couldn't redirect it(A) into another new blog.As it is(A) domain only(No hosting), Can i redirect that domain(A) into my another website (B) which has Hosting in it(B) ??

Comment: Hmmm... You can create A as domain alias on your B Control Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your DNS settings for your domain (of website A) to point to the IP address of your server for website B or also simply use a CNAME record which would point to your FQDN for website B, for example: www.websiteA.com CNAME www.websiteB.com.

There may be further configuration required for your host so they know to serve your website from requests to websiteA.com.

Note: This will continue to display as www.websiteA.com/page in your browser and not do a true redirect to www.websiteB.com/page.